# Converting decimal time to hours and minutes for display in C++

Tags: c++

this is one part of my current assignment and these are the instructions.

> printEvent() — a function that "pretty-prints" an event to the
>   console. Times should be printed in hh:mm format, rather than as
>   decimal numbers. For example, the event Spanish 101, starting at 10.0
>   and ending at 11.5 should print as `10:00 - 11:30 Spanish 101`

Currently starting time and ending time are in arrays and so I know how to access them through for loops but I am not sure how I would split 11.5 or just convert it to 11:30 and display it.

EDIT: Thanks to Paddy I think I know how to solve it now although it might not be the most efficient way. I am just going to floor the each floating number then subtract it from the original to get the difference. Multiply that by 6 to get the minutes. thank you guys!

Comment: Maybe http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cmath/modf/ then x60 on the fractpart

Comment: I am not sure i am allowed to use mods for my project haha or how to get mods for that matter. I just want to be able to get the fraction part out and then I guess i can multiply by 60 to easily get the answer.

Answer (score 3):

This is just a case of understanding the units.  Your times are given in *hours*.  To convert to *minutes*, you multiply by 60.  If you truncate that off to an integer, you can then do integer division (by 60) to get the hours, and integer modulo (by 60) to get the minutes.

```
double time = 10.5;
int time_mins = (int)floor( time * 60.0 );
int hours = time_mins / 60;
int minutes = time_mins % 60;
```

If you're not allowed to use *any* kind of modulo arithmetic, you can use a slight variation:

```
double time = 10.5;
int hours = (int)floor( time );
int minutes = (int)( 60.0 * (time - (double)hours) );
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. We are allowed to use modulus and so I tried the code from your first response on it's own to try and understand whats going on but when i try to compile it gives me an error saying floor was not compiled.

Comment: You need to include `<cmath>`, or you can just cast directly without floor.  It's similar (though not equivalent), but for your needs probably enough: `(int)( time * 60.0 )`.

Answer (score 0):

1 Hour and 30 Minutes converts into 1,5 Hours by 1hour+30/60minutes. So when your trying to convert backwards, take everything behind the comma and multiply by 6 for your minutes.

Comment: Yeah, that's what they are asking _how to do_.

Comment: float currentTime =array[0];
int hourCounter= (int)currentTime;
float minuteCounter = currentTime - hourCounter;
minuteCounter * 60 gives minutes

Answer (score 0):

first of all split the starting and ending time on the basis of point(.) 
then take the first part left to point as a minutes save them then take the right part and make it percentage by dividing by 60 e.g 30/60 . 
you can do it

Comment: That would be the opposite.